# AWS - Why there is no Interface Endpoint (PrivateLink) for S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, endpoint, amazon-vpc

The VPC Gateway endpoint for S3 is an entry in a routing table of a subnet, not an ENI/IP Interface Endpoint such as for ELB, Athena, API GW, etc.

Why there is no Interface Endpoint for S3?

Answer (score 1):

S3 and DynamoDB VPC endpoints (gateway endpoints) were introduced first and didn't leverage AWS PrivateLink, which was introduced later. All other service endpoints utilized PrivateLink from the get-go and therefore offer ENI type of interface.

Comment: Thanks for the followup, however is there a specific reason not to have private link for S3?

Comment: @mon I don't have the info on how it works under covers, but I think it might be because it would break millions of existing configurations across numerous customer accounts. S3 being "global" service might also be a factor, but it's a guess